# Should all subsections of a paper start on a new page?

Tags: paper-submission, formatting, bachelor

I am finalising a paper that is around 85 pages long. It consists of six main sections with a bunch of subsections. Should every subsection start on a new page? What is the convention concerning this? And should a subject also start on a new page after an introductory paragraph of its parent section? For instance:

---

> 3. Balloons are funny
>
> In this section I will first present reasons why balloons should not be used on occasions that are depressing. For
> instance, bringing balloons to a funeral will not cheer people up.
> Secondly I will discuss different colours that can lead to different
> reactions. As an example one should not bring red balloons to a bull
> pen. Lastly I will make clear why clowns should always have balloons
> with them as to not come across evil.
>
> > <-- PAGE BREAK? -->
>
> 3.1 Balloons are not a go-to cheer up tool
>
> When confronted with a sad or depression situation, a first reaction might be to try and
> cheer everybody up. One should be careful with the methods he uses
> though. Do not tell a joke about cancer patients if someone just
> deceased after months of chemo. Do not bring balloons to a funeral.

---

Hopefully this ad lib writing makes my question clear. (If it is any help, my institution uses APA as a style guide.)

Comment: Related question on Graphic Design SE: [What is the purpose of always locating/starting new chapters on odd pages?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/35769/19174)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the length and complexity of the work, you choose the top level sectioning.

- For **short works** -- scientific paper, lecture notes < 80 pages, etc., you in general use only **sections** and lower.
- For longer works -- thesis, long lecture notes, books, etc., you in general use **chapters**, **sections** and lower.
- If your **long work has multiple sort-of separated parts,** you can add **parts** -- notice, however, that usually, part numbering is independent. Therefore for instance Part I contains chapters 1, 2, 3 with some sections, and Part II contains chapers starting from 4, ...

Now, the standard way to go is to start parts and chapters on a new page, and leave sections running through the pages.

Needed to say, most standard publications (articles, conference abstracts, theses, books by standard publishers, ...) have to comply with some guidelines provided by the publisher, and these guidelines are usually very restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

In general, publishers (e.g., books, journal articles) and universities (e.g., theses) have style guides. They vary in the degree to which they provide comprehensive recommendations (e.g., about exactly when to insert a new page). In the absence of any style guide from the publisher, or where the style guide does not provide direction, many disciplines have style guides (e.g., APA style). And beyond that, you can probably infer rules from conventions or use common sense about clarity.

Here are some general rules that I have seen regarding page breaks:

- Chapters start on new pages. This is true whether it is a book or a thesis.
- Sections of a journal article or chapter rarely start on a new page either at submission stage or in the final formatted manuscript.

In APA Style, when you are preparing a manuscript for journal submission. Abstract, Introduction, References, Appendices, Tables, and Figures all start on new pages. Other subsections (e.g., Method, Results, Discussion, etc.) do not start on new pages. Note these rules (particularly regarding tables and figures) are different when preparing an APA style thesis (e.g., tables and figures would typically be presented in text and not on new pages).